# OpenInviter and Gmail?

Tags: gmail, invite

All the services except Gmail seems to be working in OpenInviter (http://openinviter.com/). Does anybody know why this is happening, or is my installation just bust? I'm using version 1.8.1

Comment: For me, it works locally but not on the server. Kinda strange

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it appears that fetching contacts can be done only using Secure URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, related to a large set of contacts and timeout settings.

So, in brief, test an account that doesn't have a lot of contacts.  Also, insure that you are using the right password. :)

After getting a small account working and along with better bandwidth, never had a problem again, even with accounts with huge amount of contacts.

Comment: Another thing, if you have a large amount of contacts in gmail, but sure to override the timeout var and set it a bit higher.